# Convergence in $L_p$ of $Tf(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} K(x, y)f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $K: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function such that $\sup\limits_{x} \int_{\mathbb{R}} |K(x, y)|^p dy < \infty$.

Given $f \in L^1(\mathbb{R}, dx)$, show that $Tf(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} K(x, y)f(x)dx$ belongs to $L^p(\mathbb{R}, dy)$.

I'm aware of the fact that I should apply Holder's Inequality, the problem is I'm not getting something that bounds the outer.

Answer (score 0):

Assume without loss of generality that $f$ is non-negative and has integral one. Apply Jensen's inequality to the probability measure given by
$\mu(A)=\int_A f(x)dx$ in order to get
$$
\left\lvert Tf(y)\right\rvert^p\leqslant\int_{\mathbb R}\left\lvert K(x,y)\right\rvert^pf(x)dx.
$$
Integrate over $y$ to get the result.